# Angularjs | Search JsonArray for specific value

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs

I've simplified this as much as possible. 
I'm using angularjs, I have a controller with an array of json objects like this:

```
controller('simpleC', function ($scope) {

  $scope.myArrayOfValues = [
    {
       "name" : "name1",
       "extra": "data"
    },
    {
       "name" : "name2",
       "extra": "data"
    },
    {
       "name" : "name3",
       "extra": "data"
    }
  ];
});
```

In my html view I want to quickly find a specific json object from that  array based on the value of name. Obviously what I have written below is wrong but the result of it is what I want.

```
<div ng-show="myArrayOfValues['name2']"></div>
```

Is there an angular feature I can use to go about this that will avoid me having to create a for loop or hash map?

Comment: `{{ (myArrayOfValues | filter : {name: 'name2' })[0].extra }}`

Comment: Thank you @doogabides! This was the easiest to use. You should write it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use a [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter). Let's say you have a list.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in myArrayOfValues">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Now let's say you want to search for a name using an exact match.

```
<input ng-model="search.name"><br>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in myArrayOfValues | filter:search:true">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

The last parameter, `true` is what makes it an exact match. You can leave the last parameter off or set it to false for a case insensitive substring search.

Answer (score 2):

---

I think the best way it to create a filter

```
app.filter('getObj', [
    function() {
        return function(input,val) {
            var r,i;
            for(i; i<input.length;i++) {
                if (input[i].name === val) {
                   r = input[i];
                   break;
                }
            };
            return r;
        };
    }
]);
```

then you could use it on this way

```
<div ng-show="myArrayOfValues|getObj('name2')"></div>
```

or maybe just format your json in another way to use it the way you like

```
  $scope.myArrayOfValues = {
       name1 :  {
           "name" : "name1",
           "extra": "data"
        },
        name2 : {
           "name" : "name2",
           "extra": "data"
        },
        name3 : {
           "name" : "name3",
           "extra": "data"
        }
      };
```

and

```
<div ng-show="myArrayOfValues['name2']"></div>
```

will work fine.

---